# Воспроизведение аудиофайла в Jquery

Tags: jquery

Всем привет. Как реализовать в Jquery, чтобы при каждом клике аудиофайл проигрывался всего один раз. То есть чтобы аудиофайл не был зациклен.

```js
$('.block').on( 'click', function () {

//Без повторное воспроизведение аудиофайла при каждом клике.//

});
```

Comment: Ваш код не отображается

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/977995/256824

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из личного опыта - реализовывал это так:

```
 let audio = new Audio('/path/to/audio/audio_file_name.wav');
 audio.volume = 1;
 audio.play();
```

Comment: Как я понимаю это чистый javascript)?

Comment: абсолютно верно

Comment: Если его использовать в jquery с точки зрения грамотности это будет корректно?

Comment: [jQuery](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) - это библиотека для javacript. Так что криминала тут никакого нет

Comment: Благодарю вас сударь)))

Answer (score 0):

Тут  решается простым `HTML 5`. [Документация](http://htmlbook.ru/html/audio).

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/error.mp3" type="audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis">
  <source src="ahttps://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/error.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 </audio>
```

Добавляем зацикливание:

```html
<audio loop="loop" controls>
  <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/error.mp3" type="audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis">
  <source src="ahttps://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/error.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```